# Previous call to approve is mandatory?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-20-approve

I was trying [this tutorial](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/) that implements a simple DEX.
I am specially interested in the non payable function sell, that exchange custom tokens for ETH.

```
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
    uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    emit Sold(amount);
}
```

It is always mandatory for the user to call the approve function of the ERC20 Smart Contract to be sold? Is there any way to do both steps (approve/sell) in a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to invoke `approve()` for a contract if it uses `transferFrom()`.

Some tokens support a special value of `token.approve(spender, uint256(-1))` to indicate approval for every operation.

There's a draft [EIP 2612 - permit – 712-signed approvals](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612) the introduces `permit()` which is a sort of approve that can be combined with `transferFrom()` in a single call. It is recent so not every token has support for it, Uniswap and Dai has something similar.